# Fix warning: cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter

Tags: ios, networking, httprequest, compiler-warnings

I use in my application `QHTTPOperation.{h/m}` found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Listings/Networking_QHTTPOperation_m.html) all work properly but I got 8 warnings as follow:

> Writable atomic property 'acceptableStatusCodes' cannot pair a
>   synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter
>
> Writable atomic property 'acceptableContentTypes' cannot pair a
>   synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter
>
> Writable atomic property 'authenticationDelegate' cannot pair a
>   synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter
>
> ...

I am asking because I have noticed that in the project of the above link there is no Warnings related to `QHTTPOperation.{h/m}.`

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

declare the property `nonatomic`.

because the compiler does not verify a user-defined accessor's implementation is atomic or nonatomic, it assumes it is *not* atomic. this is a pretty safe assumption considering the actual implementation uses object level spin locks (in some cases), and the data which backs the implementation is abstracted from us. the only way we *could* fulfill the contact is by using the (private) runtime functions which the compiler uses, and then the compiler would have to verify the calls and parameters were correct in this scenario. thus, the user-defined accessor is not guaranteed to fulfill the standard objc runtime atomic contract.

Comment: I'd love to know why this solves the problem of having two get/sets.

Comment: @LouFranco because if i remove '@synthesize' i will get another warning '@property' needs '@synthesize', so if i remove both all the self. acceptableStatusCodes will be errors

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@synthesize` for these properties. They provided get/set.

EDIT: For clarity.  In the .h, they declare acceptableStatusCodes with

```
NSIndexSet *        _acceptableStatusCodes;
```

and

```
@property (copy,   readwrite) NSIndexSet *          acceptableStatusCodes;
```

Then, in the .m, they have

```
@synthesize acceptableStatusCodes = _acceptableStatusCodes;
```

and

```
- (NSIndexSet *)acceptableStatusCodes
{
    return [[self->_acceptableStatusCodes retain] autorelease];
}

- (void)setAcceptableStatusCodes:(NSIndexSet *)newValue
{
    if (self.state != kQRunLoopOperationStateInited) {
        assert(NO);
    } else {
        if (newValue != self->_acceptableStatusCodes) {
            [self willChangeValueForKey:@"acceptableStatusCodes"];
            [self->_acceptableStatusCodes autorelease];
            self->_acceptableStatusCodes = [newValue copy];
            [self didChangeValueForKey:@"acceptableStatusCodes"];
        }
    }
}
```

These two blocks (the synthesize and the message implemenations) both define the same messages, so they are in conflict.  The set message does an extra check at the beginning that the auto-generated synthesize will not do (the check for kQRunLoopOperationStateInited), so I would remove the synthesize, which is being ignored anyway.

The set message is correctly implementing copy semantics with

```
 self->_acceptableStatusCodes = [newValue copy];
```

And it releases the old value.  It also does keyValue change notification.  I don't know why they left in the synthesize -- it looks like they might have wanted the state check later, and forgot to remove the auto-generated get/set.

Comment: which could be fatal, if the properties are defined with other attributes like retain...

Comment: If you look at the code, they declared it copy and the setter they provided does a copy correctly.